# Kurento Hello World, not returning loopback

Tags: webrtc, kurento

I am trying to setup the basic hello world example.

I am using a t2.micro instance with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I have the github code for the example on my local machine.

The url I am using is:
https://localhost:8443/index.html?ws_uri=wss://ec2INSTANCE:8888&ice_servers=[{"urls":"stun:stun.l.google.com"}]#

I do not have the stun or turn configured on the server, but it should be ok since I am passing the stun server to use in the url.

Any advice on this?

I just checked my console and I see this, even though port 8888 is open in AWS Security group that this instance is in

```
VM8812:35 WebSocket connection to 'wss://ec2Instance:8888/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get past the issues that I was seeing

- Follow basic instructions on a fresh EC2  (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS), using http://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation_guide.html
- Add a STUN server in conf

  - Using stun:173.194.66.127:19302
  - Tested with http://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/
- Secure WS to use WSS, which is required due to HTTPS requirement since Chrome 47, using http://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/mastering/securing-kurento-applications.html#configure-javascript-applications-to-use-https

  - Uncomment secure section of /etc/kurento/kurento.conf.js
  - Create the self signed certificate, and placed in /etc/kurento
  - Go to https://ec2InstanceUrl:8433/kurento and accept insecure connection
- Go to example https://ec2InstanceUrl:8443

You must verify that your STUN server is working by seeing something similar to the below image, with the srflx under Component Type.
[image: verify STUN/TURN]