# How do I run kurento in a docker container, with kurento hello world example on host machine

Tags: docker, kurento

I have cloned [kurento docker](https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-docker/tree/master/docker) so that I could use the kurento server in a container. And I am using the kurento-hello-world javascript version.

I use the following settings

```
  "net":
    {
        "websocket":
        {
            "port": "8888",
            "secure":
            {
                "port": "8080",
                "certificate": "defaultCertificate.pem",
                "password": ""
            },
            "path": "kurento",
            "threads": "10"
        }
    }
```

I have also configured the stun server for kurento

```
"WebRtcEndpoint":
        {
            "stunServerAddress": "<173.194.66.127>",
            "stunServerPort": "<19302>",
            "configPath": "\/etc\/kurento\/modules\/kurento"
        },
```

When I build the docker image I create a self signed certificate called defaultCertificate.pem in the same folder as the configuration. As i read that the kurento server needed to be connected to securely. I expose port 8080 in the docker container.

I then start the kurento-hello-world example on the host machine running on port 8443. I access the url as follows

https://localhost:8443/index.html?ws_uri=wss://localhost:8080/kurento

The hello world example gives an sdp offer. The issue is that the hello world examples then outputs.

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://localhost:8080/kurento' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED
```

This means nothing shows up in the remote stream. And when I look at the kurento server log, nothing appears to be even logged.

In a nutshell, how do i get the hello world example to communicate with my kurento server which is running in docker.

EDIT:
I move into the docker folder of the cloned repository and I run the docker like so:

```
docker build -t kurento .
docker run -t kurento
```

I do not add -p 8080:8080 as I expose the port in my docker file. Though i have tried it this way as well.

Comment: Could you provide the command you are using to launch the Docker container?

Comment: Updated the question. I guess it has something to do with the self signed certificate that is in the container. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39986201/kurento-hello-world-not-returning-loopback?rq=1) has a similar problem, and the only difference I think  is they accept the self signed certificate. However I simply can't access the exposed port.

Comment: Yes, it could be SSL certificate. I would check first that the port 8080 is open. Try a `telnet localhost 8080`. If it can't connect, it means your problem is somewhere else. I would check that your http server in your docker container is opening that port. From the Kurento documentation: http://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/mastering/securing-kurento-applications.html#configure-javascript-applications-to-use-https
Also I would use the port 8443 (as they do in the Kurento documentation) instead of 8080 as conventionally the port 8080 is not over SSL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoops...not the brightest mistake, just had to change

```
"stunServerAddress": "<173.194.66.127>",

"stunServerPort": "<19302>",
```

to

```
"stunServerAddress": "173.194.66.127",

"stunServerPort": "19302",
```

Was looking in the wrong places.